# Spin-Orbit Coupling on Spherical Delta Shell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spinors

I'm trying to solve for the energy levels of a rigid rotor in the presence of spin-orbit coupling. In such a case, I'd have the Hamiltonian:

$H = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V_0 \delta(r-a)+\frac{e^2}{2m^2 c^2 r^3} \vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}$

and I want to solve $H \psi = E \psi$. However, I'm unsure how to do so.

I know that the rigid rotor wavefunctions are like spherical harmonics, and that the rigid rotor-- if assumed to be a spin-1/2 object-- should have eigenstates which are a superposition of $\lvert l, m-1/2 \rangle \uparrow$ and $\lvert l, m+1/2 \rangle \downarrow $. But how do I combine all of this into a single energy eigenvalue? I don't have a radial wavefunction to work with...

Comment: Isn't the rigid rotor Hamiltonian ${\vec L}^2/2I$?